# ffmpeg can't convert mp4 to mp3 Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I can't convert mp4 file to mp3 via ffmpeg. I tried these commands but they are not working and show the same error:

> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

These are the commands:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy  -f mpegts output.mp3

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame output.mp3

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k output.mp3

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -f wav - | \
       lame -V 3 - output.mp3
```

Please help me.

this is log -> `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -vn output.mp3`

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libtheora --enable-libxvid --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libopus --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfaac
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-05-11 00:18:13
  Duration: 00:44:01.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 61 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 0 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-11 00:18:13
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: The input has no audio!

Comment: yes u r right i'm sorry ; thank you my hero.. last question please answer it in below in order to give you best answer ;)
what's the difference between it and what's high quality ?`
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame output.mp3
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -f mp3 -ab 192k output.mp3`
and thank you

Comment: The first cmd manually sets an encoder and no bitrate. The 2nd relies on ffmpeg to select the encoder and manually sets 192k as bitrate. In practice, ffmpeg will select the same encoder in the 2nd cmd and use 128k as bitrate in the 1st cmd. So, 2nd cmd is better.

Comment: Try updating to latest ffmpeg ..i got same error while executing "ffmpeg x.mp3 y.aac" in ffmpeg 3.4 , But same works in ffmpeg 4.1 without any issues

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Your Input Video may not contain Audio Stream.